Why do communists claim that capitalism began at the Industrial Revolution?
Advocates for socialism or communism often throw around phrases like "capitalism has been around for only 200 years and already threatened a mass extinction" or "before the industrial revolution, common ownership of the means of production was just what people did!"
But that doesn't make sense to me as I understand it. Capitalism is defined as private ownership of the means of production, right? Where "means of production" means things people need to survive, like land and farms and other businesses that produce important things? But before the Industrial Revolution, private individuals definitely owned land, and ran their own farms and other businesses.

"Capitalism is defined as private ownership of the means of production, right?" -- only in dictionaries. You won't find that def even in a typical econ textbook https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/19913/definition-of-capitalism

Needs a clear citation from a standard reference book on Marxism for the claim.  Otherwise this is just hearsay and weasel words  "Advocates for socialism"  Who are these advocates.  Are they speaking rhetorically? What is the context?

@JamesK, although anecdotal, I have heard this stated by self-proclaimed Communists at least 12 times. I'd never noticed it until I read this question, but it's a prevalent opinion amongst those I've spoken to.

Wikipedia: "There is no universally agreed upon definition of capitalism. ... Scholars who are uncritical of capitalism rarely actually use the term "capitalism". Some doubt that the term "capitalism" possesses valid scientific dignity, and it is generally not discussed in mainstream economics, with economist Daron Acemoglu suggesting that the term "capitalism" should be abandoned entirely. Consequently, understanding of the concept of capitalism tends to be heavily influenced by opponents of capitalism and by the followers and critics of Karl Marx."

A thing to remember is that "capitalism" is a pejorative term coined by Karl Marx. Whose meaning is vague. Though its primarily use case seems to be to invoke the image of evil bankers cackling maniacally while rubbing coins together riding in a carriage driving over the emaciated skeletons of the common man. Though in practice it seems to be a term that is applied to any economic system that is not a socialist/communist system.

There's actually a book discussing this very topic.  See:  "Capitalism and the Historians" There's a discussion of what changed with the Industrial Revolution and how it was perceived then and how it's thought of now. But the short answer is that Questor is right, originally "Capitalism" was anything a Marxist disapproved of, and the other definitions only came along later in an attempt to make the word useful for purposes other than propaganda.

Scholars who are uncritical of capitalism rarely actually use the term "capitalism".  - what term do those scholars use, @R.M.?

@AnoE "Free market/trade" might be a common one.

@AnoE It's a verbatim quote from Wikipedia. If you click through the provided link, you'll find the statement is referenced.


Capitalism is defined as private ownership of the means of production, right?

No.
One of the key features of the capitalist mode of production, is the existence of two predominant classes, one class (the bourgeoisie) who have private ownership of the means of production, and another class (the proletariat) who own nothing but their own labour.
The ownership of the bourgeoisie and the wage slavery of the proletariat may seem to have its analogy in the feudal lord and the serf in the sense that the relations are essentially exploitative, but the legal and practical status of the serf was as the owner and possessor of a hereditary (and typically inalienable) landholding.
The right of the feudal lord corresponded less with what we nowadays think of as commercial ownership, but more with what we would think of as a right of taxation by a semi-public authority.
Today, every householder has the obligation to pay council tax, but the local council does not have anything recognised as ownership over the holdings of the taxpayer. The serf had various obligations of service in kind to the feudal landlord (as did the landlord have such obligations to his feudal superior), but the serf had the majority of what are regarded as the important property rights such as the right of possession, and control over his own activity on his land.
The feudal landlord had no power to choose his serf, evict the serf from the land, or control closely how and when the work on the land was done by the serf, as a bourgeois employer might do so.
Meanwhile, the true slave is distinguished from the proletarian and the serf, in that the slave does not even own his body or labour, which belong entirely to the master.
There are other characteristics of capitalism that can be analysed, but it's important not to associate the mere existence of any one factor with it - such as private property, trade, markets, profits, or exploitation - and then immediately proceed to the conclusion that it is actually timeless and that generations of political economists have not understood anything of what they were talking about when distinguishing capitalism from other modes.
The definition of a mode of production is when there are certain kinds of classes who have certain kinds of relations to one another, and those certain relations become the most prevalent or commonplace relations in a society.
To illustrate the importance of looking at the predominant relations, the mere fact that someone is being kept illegally in a basement somewhere in the capitalist world, does not from the fact alone mean that we all live under slavery or that a system of slavery has always existed.

@NoSingularities, I'm getting a sense of deja vu here. I suspect someone made the same comment previously and I replied in the same terms I'm about to, but it has been (unhelpfully) cleaned up since by the mods. The "capitalist mode of production" is a Marxist term, and the OP explicitly references "communism", hence my answer proceeds in these terms. Also, the critical analysis that Marx performed on capitalism is still regarded as current and unsurpassed - I'm not clear what other explanation or analysis would be advanced in this context.

@NoSingularities, and how would that alternative theory, which is unrelated to what any kind of communist thinks, better answer the OPs question about what communists think?

@NoSingularities, it does evaluate the merits of the underlying claim, by being clear how the capitalist mode of production is actually defined. I'm unclear what you're complaining about. The OP set the communist context explicitly, identifying what he thought was an inconsistency. I concede my answer proceeds from Marxist tenets, as it seems at a glance does every other answer. I'm not sure why you think that's inappropriate? I accept some criticise Marx for a class analysis - those critics are, essentially, the class who Marx identifies as exploiters.

Marxist economic/social theory assumes that there is a natural progression in the development of societies, where one state necessarily leads to the next. According to Marx, before there is a capitalist mode of production there must be a feudal mode of production to set the preconditions for the development of the capitalist mode of production. (For orthodox Marxists, the Maoist position that one could have a peasant-based revolution was utter heresy.)
The transition is never instantaneous and clean. Between feudalism and capitalism, there was mercantilism, for instance. But broadly speaking, feudalism is defined by agricultural land being the dominant mode of production, while in capitalism it is factories.
You point out that people did own their farms prior to the industrial revolution. In theory, that would be the exception for central Europe. The nobles held their lands in fief from the king, and the king held it by divine right or in sort-of-fief from the pope. Anything else was already part of the transition to capitalism.

In Marxist theory, control of the means of production is the essence of all class division. When one class owns (has control over) the means of production, other classes can be subjugated because they need access to those means of production in order to do their work and provide for themselves and their families. Marx is pointing out what these days we call a gate-keeper model: the class that owns the means of production becomes a gate-keeper, and can impose whatever rules or extract whatever payment it likes from those who need access. This is true of every class-based mode of production, not just capitalism.
In capitalism, the capitalist class controls the means of production not through direct ownership of the land or instruments used for production, but through the commodification and control of the materials produced. In Feudalism, a lord owned the land on which things were produced, but the laborers who actually produced things lived on that land full time and and owned what they produced, only being obliged to pay rent, tithes, and/or taxes on their income. That could be an onerous burden, at times — hence the resentments that led to the 16th century Liberalism movement — but laborers still owned what they produced first and then had it extracted by the feudal gate-keeper. Capitalism inverted that by closing off production in industrial settings, barring entry to any worker unwilling to follow the rules, and claiming the entire productive output as the property of the owner. This is the essence of wage slavery: in order to work (and thus to eat, have housing, etc.) a worker must cede all rights to anything he helps produce and accept a flat wage for the time spent working, regardless of how productive that time might actually be.
We can see the beginnings of the capitalist mode of production perhaps back into the 17th century, when various companies and national entities began exploiting foreign territories: using native labor to extract resources, which were then sold at market for whatever profits could be made. But true capitalism arose with the industrial era, when closed production venues meant that laborers could be entirely excluded from any ownership of the material they produced. So yes, capitalism is 200-300 years old, at best.

A somewhat boring point that hasn't been mentioned is that socialists and other political groups inspired by Karl Marx's work use this definition because Marx used this definition, and Marx used this definition because Adam Smith used this definition.
So, at least in Marx's time, capitalists would have agreed that this was when capitalism started.

Please provide a direct quote for this statement, ideally from the original source.

By one definition at least, that of shared-based public companies, Capitalism started in the 17th century or so as it was first leveraged to limit exposure to spice trade to the Far East.  Ships could be fabulously lucrative upon return, but took years to do so and were not infrequently lost, making it better to spread the risks amongst a number of ventures.  That's what shares, and the ability to buy and sell them, were all about.
The Dutch East India Company, or VOC, est. 1602, certainly being one of most notorious ever such enterprises, along with its good buddy the British East India Company, or EIC, est. 1600.
Having gotten that out of the way, what the Industrial Revolution did was to add other essential innovations.  Besides steam power that included notions like component-based manufacturing of firearms (i.e. have specialized workers make the same parts on repeat, which are then assembled, as opposed to a craftsman making all of one gun from start to end).
This brought to the fore factory based labor and got the poor off the land, into the cities, begetting Dicken's dark satanic mills of horrible working conditions.

In their thousands they moved from the countryside into the rapidly-growing towns, to man scores of new factories. The Industrial Revolution actually began long before Victoria came to the throne, but increased in speed and force as the 19th-century progressed. In 1773 fewer than 14,000 people lived in Manchester. Before the century ended there were 70,000. By 1900 the population had shot up to over half a million. A French critic and historian described it in the 1860s as “a Babel built of brick.”


The simple peasants who left their insanitary country hovels and back-breaking slavery on the land, or the “cottage industries” killed off by new production methods, believed they were moving into a world of bright lights and easy jobs “minding the machines.” They could not have been more wrong. They were merely exchanging one kind of slavery for another, in even worse circumstances.

Now, when Marx talks about the Proletariat, he talks about factory workers.  Farmers don't count.

f. Peasantry and Farmers. Marx considered the peasantry to be disorganized, dispersed, and incapable of carrying out change.

Early Soviet Communism is full of distrust at the capacity to socially mobilize farmers (that message apparently needed some tuning and massaging in order for Communist doctrine to appeal in China and poor countries in Latin America and Africa).
The existence of Capitalism, by itself, did not create the proletariat, that did have to wait till the Industrial Revolution.
So perhaps a better way to put things is that prior to the industrial revolution the essential ingredients for Communism to take over from its arch-enemy, Capitalism, were lacking, according to Communist doctrine.
Whether that goes as far as Communists somehow arguing that Capitalism didn't exist before?  That is possible.  Here's one source that claiming so: Introduction to Karl Marx, Module on Stages of Development:


feudal or estate property: "Like tribal and communal ownership, it is based again on a community; but the directly producing class standing over against it is not, as in the case of the ancient community, the slaves, but the enserfed small peasantry"




capitalism: because of the eventual growth of commerce (and of human populations), feudal society began to accumulate capital, which, along with the increased debt incurred by the aristocracy, eventually led to the English Revolution of 1640 and the French Revolution of 1789, both of which opened the way for the establishment of a society structured around commodities and profit (i.e. capitalism).


Whatever other intellectual hoops Marx uses to put forward his claims and to define Capitalism, 1789 puts us right at the start of the Industrial Revolution.

Beginning in Great Britain, the Industrial Revolution spread to continental Europe and the United States, from around 1760 to about 1820–1840. This transition included going from hand production methods to machines; new chemical manufacturing and iron production processes; the increasing use of water power and steam power; the development of machine tools; and the rise of the mechanised factory system. Output greatly increased, and the result was an unprecedented rise in population and the rate of population growth. The textile industry was the first to use modern production method and textiles became the dominant industry in terms of employment, value of output, and capital invested.

Again, there was plenty of capital invested before the Industrial Revolution, this was the raison d'être for the creation of the VOC and EIC almost 200 years before.  But it wasn't quite the right kind of Capitalism for Communism to germinate from.

In an alternate, Capitalism-missing, universe in which factories somehow developed under the tutelage of Feudal lords, what makes anyone think worker conditions would have somehow been all that different and thus immune to Communism?

Thanks for mentioning stocks. This answer is closest so far to getting it right: capitalists have trouble imagining that the mere movement of securities can impoverish or damage the working classes, and so can't see the harms of stock exchanges and incorporation when compared to the Industrial Revolution's orphan-grinders.

@ItalianPhilosopher Afai understand it Marx thought that the mode of production was crucial for the makeup of society. So the feudal society is seen as more of a necessity of a primary agrarian economy, which increase output and capabilities by size of farmland and raw materials, but which then runs into logistical problems that no longer allow for master - slave relations but morph into localized agency of landlords and tenant ownership where de jure the king is the master but de facto the power moves  down to the aristocracy.

@ItalianPhilosopher 2/ And similarly industrial capitalism would form it's own society shaped by the necessities of it's mode of production. So while colonialism started earlier and already required a lot of the elements of capitalism, investments, banking transfer o assets, money lending etc, it was still probably by and large seen as an extension of feudal imperialism and trade especially as that was far away. But with the advent of the industrial revolution those features became visible to even the most sleepy observers.

@ItalianPhilosopher 3/ Or lets be real to the people in their small villages and cities who hadn't seen or heard of much of the world. But industrial production put loads of artisan producers out of work, relegated agriculture to 2nd place and made the cities grow, desert the rural areas, so that everyone could see here is happening something truly new and revolutionary. And this new system no longer required an empire but thought to establish a universal rule of law protecting property rights anywhere and everywhere.

@ItalianPhilosopher 4/ So for Marx there is no non-capitalist industrialization under the tutelage of a feudal lord, industrialization would breed capitalism or vice versa and that alone would create the social conditions of a global, densely packed industrial under class, numerous and able to have a society of their own but tied down by property rights, which just needed to rid itself of their bosses, who have no real power anyway anymore. So conversely a peasant revolution was not what Marx had in mind as in his thought that would only ever reproduce the feudal society.

@ItalianPhilosopher 5. Whether that was the correct interpretation of events is questionable to begin with, but the whole USSR thing and especially the later revolutions of colonial countries run counter to Marx idea that the most developed countries working class will start the revolution and rid themselves of it's chains. Also capitalism isn't the arch-enemy but the previous step in the progression, he actually praised that for it's successes and encouraged people in feudal societies to support those liberals. Though ultimately thought it would self-destruct and give rise to something new.

@ItalianPhilosopher: The Russian Empire pretty much jumped directly from Feudalism to Communism without much of a Capitalist intermediate period.


before the industrial revolution, common ownership of the means of production was just what people did!

This is not correct. The predecessor of Capitalism is Feudalism, the predecessor of Feudalism is slavery.
Capitalism initiated its revolution because to build a factory, you need workers to hire. Where do you get them if under Feudalism peasants are not allowed to leave the lord?

Cities, of course. Improved agricultural output allowed cities to grow.

@MSalters In cities, you got the noble city citizens, craftsmen and indeed some servants and poor, but not really enough for capitalism. The abolishment of serfdom was really a necessary reform for manufacturers and other ventures to be able to start and flourish. At least in Central Europe (e.g., Austrian Empire).

@VladimirFГероямслава: That logic would be problematic in Northern Europe; Scandinavia didn't have serfdom. Why didn't it lead the industrial revolution then? (it's not good farming country, of course). This is of course the same flaw that Lenin had to address in Russia: orthodox communism prescribed a linear model, but Lenin wanted to go from Feudalism straight to Communism. Scandinavia also "skipped" serfdom.

@MSalters What? Your logic is backwards.

Frame Challenge: Marx did not claim Capitalism started only 200 years ago
There's no clearly defined start date for the Industrial Revolution, but most sources pick the 1760s or 1750s as the approximate decade when it began. Karl Marx did not assert that capitalism began only during the Industrial Revolution. Rather, he viewed capitalism as a system that had roots in Europe's transformation starting from the 14th century, particularly with the decline of feudalism.
Direct quotes from Marx
Marx traced the formation of capitalism to historical events that spanned several centuries. His concept of primitive accumulation explained how capitalist society began to take shape. Below are the most relevant quotes from the 1887 English translation of "Das Kapital".
Decline of Feudalism (Late 14th - early 15th century)
Factors like the Black Death reduced the population, undermining the feudal system and increasing the bargaining power of laborers.

The economic structure of capitalist society has grown out of the economic structure of feudal society. The dissolution of the latter sets free the elements of the former.

— Capital, Volume I, Chapter 26
Privatization of agricultural land (Enclosure Movement) (late 14th - early 17th century)
Marx noted that the privatization of common lands in England created a class of wage laborers and a capitalist class.

Now that we have considered the forcible creation of a class of outlawed proletarians, the bloody discipline that turned them into wage labourers, the disgraceful action of the State which employed the police to accelerate the accumulation of capital by increasing the degree of exploitation of labour, the question remains: whence came the capitalists originally? For the expropriation of the agricultural population creates, directly, none but the greatest landed proprietors. As far, however, as concerns the genesis of the farmer, we can, so to say, put our hand on it, because it is a slow process evolving through many centuries. The serfs, as well as the free small proprietors, held land under very different tenures, and were therefore emancipated under very different economic conditions. In England the first form of the farmer is the bailiff, himself a serf. His position is similar to that of the old Roman villicus, only in a more limited sphere of action. During the second half of the 14th century he is replaced by a farmer, whom the landlord provided with seed, cattle and implements. His condition is not very different from that of the peasant. Only he exploits more wage labour. Soon he becomes a metayer, a half-farmer. He advances one part of the agricultural stock, the landlord the other. The two divide the total product in proportions determined by contract. This form quickly disappears in England, to give the place to the farmer proper, who makes his own capital breed by employing wage labourers, and pays a part of the surplus-product, in money or in kind, to the landlord as rent. So long, during the 15th century, as the independent peasant and the farm-labourer working for himself as well as for wages, enriched themselves by their own labour, the circumstances of the farmer, and his field of production, were equally mediocre. The agricultural revolution which commenced in the last third of the 15th century, and continued during almost the whole of the 16th (excepting, however, its last decade), enriched him just as speedily as it impoverished the mass of the agricultural people.

— Capital, Volume I, Chapter 29
Discovery and exploitation of America (late 15th - early 16th century)
Marx highlighted the discovery of the Americas as a pivotal moment for early capital accumulation through colonial exploitation.

The discovery of gold and silver in America, the extirpation, enslavement and entombment in mines of the aboriginal population, the beginning of the conquest and looting of the East Indies, the turning of Africa into a warren for the commercial hunting of black-skins, signalised the rosy dawn of the era of capitalist production. These idyllic proceedings are the chief momenta of primitive accumulation. On their heels treads the commercial war of the European nations, with the globe for a theatre. It begins with the revolt of the Netherlands from Spain, assumes giant dimensions in England's Anti-Jacobin War, and is still going on in the opium wars against China, etc.

— Capital, Volume I, Chapter 31

An excellent answer, but another answer claims Marx himself said it began 200 years ago.

@PurpleP that answer doesn't have any quotes, mine provides a direct quote from Marx himself on the matter.

I'd say a large amount can probably be attributed to a general lack in history and scientific knowledge. Not just by the Marxists, but in general.
Like European history has it's classics with the Greek and Roman Republic/Empire, but after their fall, the medieval period or "middle ages", between antiquity and modernity, are pretty nebulous when it comes to history despite them covering almost a millennia (depending on where you count).
While there's a somewhat questionable quote about "victors (writing) history", there's some truth to the fact that in order to write history, you'd need to be alive and be able to write... So most often preserved history that is not archeological artifacts but passed on knowledge is likely to be by upper class or clergy who could read and write, have access to durable enough material and store it properly or who could afford access to people that were able to do so.
So one might expect there to be a "slight" bias in these stories. Like the people writing about a king still alive might be scarce with the negative parts, the king overthrowing a predecessor violently might claim how awful that last guy was and how much of a relief it is that he's gone, while a descendant of a king might praise their ancestors and in consequence themselves. Also apparently as a mix of Christianity exploiting Roman monarchs pretending to be god and "illegitimate rulers" looking for an out on the hereditary monarchy thingy, the church also stepped in an provided a legitimization of the rulers by being "chosen by god as rulers". So there was some intermingling of church and state as well.
So "history" for the most part only really started with the renaissance and the medieval period ending with an increased interest in the ancient stuff, probably printing presses also made things easier than having scribes do the copying, etc. So many of the enlightenment and classical liberal thinkers apparently just made shit up when it comes to history or believed the shit that their contemporaries had made up or what they found in dubious records. So you might look up "state of nature" were people essentially hypothesized what came before their current "civilized" societies. Like Hobbes apparently sought it was all a violent free for all and that we should submit to the leviathan of society to save us from ourselves, essentially praising absolutism. While Rousseau envisioned more of a good or neutral human being born with a blank slate and being corrupted by society.
So history beyond mere facts (such as records of wars, certificates and changing of titles and property) including the grand narratives (of why people do the things they do and stuff like that), was already pretty sketchy and might have involved a lot of speculations and fictional parts...
And another big rift probably came with the revolutions in Britain, America and France.
Because with those there apparently was a large shift in the public narrative. The monarch was no longer the good, benevolent ruler appointed by god himself for the betterment of the people and the people were all evil and being punished for their sins.
But instead they were the evil oppressing tyrant that took all the hard earned values and spend them lavishly on themselves and it was the it was the wealthy upper class who restricted the ruler (Britain), replaced it with a more worldly alternative and checks and balances (America) or when daring enough got rid of it altogether and established a republic (France).
Now in reality it was probably always more muddy as to who is actually in charge, whether the king is an absolute ruler or a populist demagogue or a puppet of the aristocracy or if their mistresses and advisors really ruled or if the wealthy lower classes who paid the upper classes' expenditures told them what to do and so on. And if people actually believed the myths of the god given rulership and whatnot or if they just said "amen" as that was what they knew made the higher ups go away and rebel if they didn't hold their end of the deal of providing security, fair jurisdiction and whatever else they claimed...
So there is a good chance that the actual change in narratives and structure was far less significant than people made it out to be. However what did change is the people righting the stories and the stories that were written.
So rather than praising authoritarianism, obedience and religious values affirming the structures of feudalism, the new narratives talked about freedom, equality, individuality and the increased productivity that came with it.
So while the French revolution originally didn't want to go for a republic but merely a constitutional monarchy and more of a reform and only went full on "off with their heads" once the aristocracy tried to block reform and roll it back. The stories that came out of those revolutions made them sound like a historic change and like true social revolutions that actually changed the makeup of society and not merely the faces of the ruling class.
So that's the kind of atmosphere in which many of the modern political ideologies were created and/or evolved in. Like conservatism that wanted to go back, liberalism which really bought that idea of individual freedom and how that turned out great or socialism which saw that "yeah that sounds nice and all, but a most that works for the upper class, the rest is merely in a different position, but not necessarily a better one".
So Marx's historic materialism seems to be based largely on those narratives. Where he extrapolated based on the accounts from the last set of revolutions that society basically leapfrogs it's way forward by class struggle. So idk the hunters might have used their force to take over society from the gatherers, the agricultural revolutions made the farmers first resource producers who then turned into kings as land ownership was the new cool and those developed for themselves an underclass of craftsmen who then developed their skills an material into machines that made them overtake the kings in power and wealth.
Just that he found that the new underclass the proletariat would be left without devices to do a leapfrog, but would have found a society already so advanced that this wouldn't be necessary but that they could just seize power and keep it running by themselves and for themselves as a community.
Now whether that idea is true to begin with is quite questionable, but it's not completely outside of the prominent narrative of the time and the observations that you could have made.
Also according to the liberal narrative this progression was from the absolute ruler to a liberal democracy (still mostly rule of the rich upper class) to the rule of all: democracy, communism, anarchy whatever you want to call it.
Another and maybe more interesting aspect of that is that in this narrative social progress is tied to the mode of production. So it's not the malevolence of the ruler that a one man show, but it's due to the necessity of the way in which a society secures it's production and survival. So if society as a whole barely makes enough to survive you can't really afford "good for nothing"-kings who don't produce food. Same for craftsman, merchant, scribes, philosophers (essentially scientists who ask stupid questions that might turn out not to be that stupid after all), if anything you might need priests for social cohesion to get some synergy effects.
Likewise feudalism is more of a matter of necessity. Like a medieval king simply couldn't rule a large empire on their own, to be relevant they'd need to be present and with week long, expensive rides between places to then also having to fight a battle, that couldn't be sustained. So the speed of information and military would limit their sphere of influence unless they give up power to underlings to rule in their name, which would need to have some agency of their own as otherwise they would constantly need to consult the king with the obvious problems. So from a king to an aristocracy of nested fiefdoms, who give up land (means of production) in exchange for a share of the profit.
Also the economic power was largely in the primary sector (agriculture, forestry, quarries, etc). So the point of money was more of an intermediary between getting goods that you wanted. Having loads of money was not really as useful as one might think. In that money was heavy gold coins that were only valid within a kingdom, could be robbed if you moved them and could only buy you so much within the confines of a single city.
So you needed craftsman, merchants and whatnot to bring the interesting stuff to the place with the money or to buy favors etc.
Now probably with a combination of wars, better production, colonialism, trade, lavish spending and status, getting money was probably more important than getting raw materials, so you had a shift to the secondary sector economy. Also with increased trade and whatnot you would need abilities to transfer assets, to secure their value outside of the jurisdiction of a king, to make investments, lend money and so on.
And that is likely what socialists see as the emergence of capitalism. When it was no longer goods for money for goods, but money for commodities for more money, which became the capitalist mode of production.
And that truly transformed society. Like when land and primary resources where the major means of production you were tied to a place and your empire is limited while now if your means of production is money in your bank account you can travel the world and operate from wherever you want and in whatever industry you want. You could make countries bribe you for staying and craft laws in your favor and you can create an entire society with the sole purpose of protecting your property rights, from which you take social and political power. Hence the politico-economical system of "capitalism".
Since then the secondary industry has been taken over by the third and fourth sector of service and optimizing service and whole economies revolve around generating money more than generating any useful goods or services or only as a by-product so in that regard we truly live in capitalism.
Also you can make the case that the money being often based on debt creates a necessity for growth (as interest rates keep the debt growing) while the actual physical economy can only grow to much and that trade only redistributes but doesn't actually create value, so money printing, bankruptcies of the poor or exploiting the planet and other places more and more and more.
Now as said it's highly dubious as to whether this progression is as sketched out or whether it is such a revolutionary new thing or a progress that is going on for much longer and that these milestones are rather artificial. But at least with regards to climate change the industrial revolution did mark a change in how we produce and how that effects the planet. And you can make the case that through increased technology in terms of transportation and communication different forms of economic and political structures became available that weren't before.
I mean for the very least, pretty much everyone is now capable of writing (history). So rather than one narrative of the powerful, for better or worse we have thousands of different narratives and perspectives on how things work and why.

I find it hard to connect this answer to the OP's question.

@Alexei Well it's not an easy question. So different milestones of history, a deliberate progression of history rather than passing of time, different definitions of what capitalism means and so on.

Your comments on the topic of historians improvising the backstory sometimes & gathering data from history after a certain point are supported in a chapter in The Great Transformation by Karl Polyani. From page 47, “the same bias which made Adam Smiths generation view primeval man as bent on barter and truck induced their successors to disavow all interest in early man…they abandoned all interests in the cultures of uncivilized; man as irrelevant to understanding the problems of our age.”. What that means is their economic data we have for theory was & is based largely on European history.1/2

At the exact same time in history there was no poverty or homelessness in all of the Americas (scarcity maybe) while in Europe millions were in misery (who then left everything they knew for unknown lands). The Europeans imported social diseases not found in the Americas. Reading native american history from native american authors, the societies looked plain or primitive on the outside often had a rich social structures. See Progress and Poverty by Henry George.

But my point is that trying to define it is difficult because it has changed and is changing over time. Prior to 1971 in England the Charter of the Forest protected the right to go into nature for survival resources. So there seemed to be a right to use the commons and then the gatekeeping, privatization and denial of the commons changed the definition again. What we need is a table of characteristics and we can see it will change over time. Time of an open frontier, time of settlement, time of chattel slavery, time of wage slavery, time of colonialism and genocide, etc

"In all primitive societies,..." says M. de Laveleye, whose work exclude no part of the world unexplored, "...the soil was the joint property of the tribes and was the subject to periodical distribution among all of the families, so that all might live by their labor as nature has ordained. The comfort of each was thus proportioned to his energy and intelligence; no one, at any rate, was destitute of the means of subsistence, and inequality increasing from generation to generation was provided against." From Progress and Poverty.

What I'm saying is that where economists filled in the blanks, like the concept of the "the god of the gaps", that's where it went wrong in my opinion. This idea of made up information you suggest is supported and that is because they excluded man in the state of nature as primitive and not important  (and for selfish reason - manifest destiny) when it was and is important to economic theory. And economists can use the scientific method now to update economic theory and some do. My comments are meant to point to sources for your comments.

The answers above seem to be avoiding the actual definition of "Capitalism" which is just the legal and economic system that allows private individuals to own capital.
Capital is economically productive assets, such as shares or bonds or property deeds. Note that this is not a trivial definition, as there are significant legal and cultural complexities that need to be properly overcome before people are confident to own what appear to be ephemeral assets.
Now, did such things come about with the Industrial Revolution? To some extent, yes. But it is not obvious that the direction of causality is in that direction. It is more accurate to state that the legal and economic developments that led to secure, long-term, private property, mixed with technological advances, led to a mutual feedback effect that resulted in the Industrial Revolution.

The "actual" definition of Capitalism? There are thousands of related definitions, and yours is not among the commonly used. You describe "rule of law" if anything. Also, it would predict that the Netherlands (having the first stock exchange in Amsterdam) would lead the Industrial Revolution. But it was famously late.

@MSalters I am not describing 'rule of law'. It depends what those laws are. The USSR had plenty of laws too, rigorously enforced.
